# jQuery ui.selectmenu not working with latest version of jQuery and Colorbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, colorbox

I am using [ui.selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) inside colorbox. It's work well with either, jQuery or colorbox having older version.

It work with below two combinations:
jQuery **1.3.2** and colorbox **1.3.8**
jQuery **1.4.2** and colorbox **1.3.0**

If does't work with:
jQuery **1.4.2** and colorbox **1.3.8**

The problem is destroy method of ui.selectmenu call immediately after init method undesirably. So **ui** effect seen for moment.

Does anyone having related issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I have created custom destroy method and call it menually when required.